# Easy localization in dropdown list change the data

Tags: flutter

How can a change the value use the specfic language in a drop down  list for example month, using easy localization in flutter.
var months =[LocalKeys.jan.tr(),LocaleKeys.feb.tr()]
but doesnot work

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: I solved this by resetting the rest to equal the same values inside my build method, i have no more information but this what worked for me.
`//class List List = [LocalKeys.jan.tr()];`
 `//reset it again inside build`
`List List = [LocalKeys.jan.tr()];`